# Find exact CPU percentage from the metrics exported by prometheus-node-exporter

Tags: prometheus, grafana, prometheus-node-exporter, thanos

I use the `node_cpu_seconds_total` metrics for this.

Basically, I want to subtract `mode="idle"` from the total CPU usage and then take the avg rate of the result, then a percentage calculation.

I tried something like:

```
100 - (avg(rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{instance="ip-X-X-X-X.eu-west-1.compute.internal:9100",job="rabbitmq-prod-node-exporter",replica="prometheus-prod"} - node_cpu_seconds_total{instance="ip-X-X-X-X.eu-west-1.compute.internal:9100",mode="idle",job="rabbitmq-prod-node-exporter",replica="prometheus-aws-prod"}))[1m] * 100)
```

But does not seem to be proper and also shows a parse error:

```
Error executing query: parse error at char 177: range specification must be preceded by a metric selector, but follows a *promql.AggregateExpr instead
```

Comment: I tried it, but ends up in no data error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fix your PromQL change it to the following:

```
100 - (avg(rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{instance="INSTANCE",job="JOB",replica="REPLICA"}[1m])) - avg(rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{instance="INSTANCE",mode="idle",job="JOB",replica="REPLICA"}[1m])) * 100)
```

But it's better to use "irate" instead of "rate" and use the following simpler PromQL:

```
100 - 100 * (avg(irate(node_cpu_seconds_total{instance="INSTANCE",job="JOB",replica="REPLICA",mode="idle"}[1m])))
```

Comment: Thanks, for the second one with irate, so you are taking the average only for the CPU with mode="idle" ?

Comment: Yes, it's enough. Note that the final result is 100% minus idle, so it's the used time.

Comment: I'd avoid using `irate`  instead of `rate` - see https://valyala.medium.com/why-irate-from-prometheus-doesnt-capture-spikes-45f9896d7832

Answer (score 5):

The following PromQL query returns the average number of CPU cores used during the last 5 minutes per each host (aka `instance`) with the installed `node_exporter`:

```
sum(1 - rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle"}[5m])) by (instance)
```

This query works in the following way:

1. The `rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle"}[5m])` calculates the average per-second change rate for every time series, which matches `node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle"}`. This is basically the average idle CPU time per each CPU core during the last 5 minutes (see `5m` lookbehind window in square brackets). See [rate()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#rate) function docs.
2. The `1 - rate(...)` subtracts per-core idle CPU time from 1, so the end result is the average per-core busy CPU time over the last 5 minutes.
3. The `sum(...) by (instance)` sums busy CPU time per each `instance` (aka host with the installed `node_exporter`). See [sum()](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#sum) function docs.

The `node_cpu_seconds_total` metric may contain additional labels, which you may want to save in the result. For example, `env`, `datacenter`, `tenant`, etc. Then just substitute `sum(...) by (instance)` with `sum(...) without (cpu, mode)` in order to save all these labels:

```
sum(1 - rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle"}[5m])) without (cpu, mode)
```