# PromQL and node-exporter: Peak CPU usage during last minute averaged over many servers

Tags: prometheus, promql, prometheus-node-exporter

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71126401/find-exact-cpu-percentage-from-the-metrics-exported-by-prometheus-node-exporter) I was trying to obtain peak CPU usage during last minute averaged over many servers. Here is my query:

```
max_over_time(sum(1-rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle",instance!="epgp003:9401"}[1m]))by(instance))
```

However I get this error:

`Error executing query: invalid parameter "query": 1:15: parse error: expected type range vector in call to function "max_over_time", got instant vector`.

If I try this:

```
max_over_time((sum(1-rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle",instance!="epgp003:9401"})[1m:]))by(instance))
```

I get this error:

`Error executing query: invalid parameter "query": 1:107: parse error: unexpected <by>`

Following query:

```
max_over_time((sum(1-rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle",instance!="epgp003:9401"}[1m]))by(instance))[1m:])
```

Yields an array of values as response, while I need only one number (the maximum).

Comment: You need range selector within max_over_time too. Something like [1m:]. Notice since this is nota vector selectors, you need to use subquery syntax (plus you might need additional parenthesis before range)

Comment: @markalex - thank you! Actually I tried that also (updated my original question). Pay attention to `instance!="epgp003:9401"` - those are many servers (because of `!=`).

Comment: To get biggest of them you can enclose your query (working one obviously) into `max( ... )`.

Comment: I did that and it seemed to work: `max(sum(1-rate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle",instance!="epgp003:9401"}[1m]))by(instance))`. I just hope it shows what I need. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, correct query will be:

```
max(
 max_over_time(
  (sum(
   1-rate(
      node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle",instance!="epgp003:9401"}
      [1m])
   ) by (instance)
  )[1m:]
 )
)
```

Here we first apply `max_over_time` over range of 1 minute, to find max value for each server over that time. And then - apply `max` to get a single maximum value among those.